# How to send Control+C through Expect in Perl?

Tags: perl

My program connects to a host using `ssh` and performs shell commands. Before executing any commands, it necessary to hit control+c in order to get a shell prompt.

```
my $exp = Expect->spawn('ssh sojohnga@sanity34-tb1')
    or die "Cannot spawn sftp command \n";
$exp->expect($timeout, ["password:"]);
$exp->send("********\n");
my $timeout1 = 10;
$exp->expect($timeout1,'-re',"UsingNobackup\s+\#\n\#{74}\n.*");
# how to send control+c here?
```

Comment: Please refer the sniffet.                                                                my $exp = Expect->spawn('ssh sojohnga@sanity34-tb1') or die "Cannot spawn sftp command \n";
$exp->expect($timeout, ["password:"]);
$exp->send("password11**\n");
my $timeout1 = 10;
$exp->expect($timeout1,'-re',"UsingNobackup\s+\#\n\#{74}\n.*");                 Now i need to hit control+c through the program.

Comment: Edit your question instead of putting additional information in a comment

Comment: Please tell me that this is not the real password....

Comment: This might be more of an `expect` question. With expect to send Ctrl-c you would do `send \003`... maybe that works in perl expect? I'm not sure, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.Tried with the above line.It actually gets the prompt where I am executing perl script, Not with the one where I am performing SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Control characters in perl are represented using `\c<character>`. See: [perlrebackslash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#All-the-sequences-and-escapes).

To send a control character using the Expect module:

```
$exp->send("\cC");
```

Comment: Hi,                                                                                                                   Thanks for your inputs.Tried with the above line.It actually gets the prompt where I am executing perl script, Not with the one where I am performing SSH.

Comment: After sending the ctrl-c, you'll need to start another `->expect(...)` loop or your script will end.  See: http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.21/Expect.pod#How_to_automate_login  for an example.